# NameError: global name 'PIN' is not defined

Tags: python, global, nameerror

I am getting the following Error Message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Volumes/KINGSTON/Programming/Assignment.py", line 17, in <module>
    Assignment()
 File "/Volumes/KINGSTON/Programming/Assignment.py", line 3, in Assignment
```

My code is:

```py
def Assignment():
    prompt = 'What is your PIN?'
    result = PIN
    error = 'Incorrect, please try again'
    retries = 2
    while result == PIN:
        ok = raw_input(Prompt)
        if ok == 1234:
            result = menu
        else:
            print error
            retries = retries - 1

        if retries < 0:
            print 'You have used your maximum number of attempts. Goodbye.'

Assignment():
```

would really appreciate a little help if anyone knows where i am going wrong and can explain

Comment: What is the program, what are you trying to do?  What have you tried to fix the problem?  Please give us a little more to go on then an error message, some code and a pat of the back to "have at it".

Answer (score 0):

That particular error is raised because when you say `result = PIN`, `PIN` doesn't actually exist. Since it isn't in quotes, Python assumes it is a variable name, but when it goes to check what that variable is equal to, it doesn't find anything and raises the `NameError`. When you fix that, it will also happen with `prompt` since you later refer to it as `Prompt`.

I'm not sure if this is your full code or not, so I'm not sure what the other issues could be, but it looks like you are using `result` and `PIN` to control your `while` loop. Remember that a `while` loop runs until the condition it is checking is `False` (or if you manually break out of it), so instead of declaring the extra variables, you could start with something like this:

```py
def Assignment():
    # No need to declare the other variables as they are only used once
    tries = 2

    # Go until tries == 0
    while tries > 0:
        ok = raw_input('What is your PIN?')
        # Remember that the output of `raw_input` is a string, so either make your
        # comparison value a string or your raw_input an int (here, 1234 is a string)
        if ok == '1234':
            # Here is another spot where you may hit an error if menu doesn't exist
            result = menu
            # Assuming that you can exit now, you use break
            break
        else:
            print 'Incorrect, please try again'
            # Little shortcut - you can rewrite tries = tries - 1 like this
            tries -= 1

        # I'll leave this for you to sort out, but do you want to show them both
        # the 'Please try again' and the 'Maximum attempts' messages?
        if tries == 0:
            print 'You have used your maximum number of attempts. Goodbye.'
```